# Lost RAR password, is there any way to access my data?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, zip, compression

I lost my winrar password of my file. I need to access it. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the strength of your password. Winrar implements proper AES-128 encryption with 262144 iterations of KDF, there's no known bypass for that. You need to estimate the number of possible passwords (what's the length, what characters were used, did it contain words, etc.), and if it is large enough to not be bruteforceble there's nothing you can do, cryptographically speaking.

The other avenue is to find the password. If it was stored in a file then you can recover it for some time after the deletion, this may well be the easiest way.